Is an arbitrary measurable function that vanish locally $\mu$-almost everywhere integrable, with integral $0$?
I came across this question when studying measure theory:
Is an arbitrary measurable function that vanish locally $\mu$-almost everywhere integrable, with integral $0$?
The motivation behind this question is that I have proved that an arbitrary measurable functions that vanish almost everywhere is integrable, with measure $0$. I did this by first using the following proposition

Proposition$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $f$ be a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $X$, and let $\{f_n\}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of functions in $\mathscr{S}_+$ such that $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ holds at each $x$ in $X$. Then $\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu$.

to deal with nonnegative functions and then using the decomposition $f=f^+-f^-$.
So I want to explore whether a similar result would hold for an arbitrary measurable function that vanish locally $\mu$-almost everywhere. But I have trouble proceeding a similar proof. So I am questioning whether this is correct or not?
Could someone please help me with it? If it is wrong, please provide a counterexample; if it is correct, please provide a proof. Thank you very much!

A property holds locally $\mu$-almost everywhere if the set of points at which it fails to hold is locally $\mu$-null.
A set $N$ is called locally $\mu$-null if for each set $A$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfies $\mu(A)<+\infty$ the set $A\bigcap N$ is $\mu$-null.

There’s no topology on your measure space, so what does “locally” mean in this context? Do you mean that $f\chi_E = 0$ a.e. for every set $E$ of finite measure?

@kieransquared I am adding the following definition to my post: A set $N$ is called locally $\mu$-null if for each set $A$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfies $\mu(A)<+\infty$ the set $A\bigcap N$ is $\mu$-null.

In general, no. Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the measure $\mu$ which assigns $0$ to the empty set and $\infty$ to any nonempty set, and let $f=1$. The only finite measure set is the empty set, and we clearly have $\mu(\emptyset \cap \{f\neq 0\}) = 0$, so $\{f\neq 0\}$ is locally $\mu$-null. But $\int_\mathbb{R}f d\mu = \mu(\mathbb{R}) =\infty$.
You need the measure space to be sigma finite. Indeed, if you can write $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ with each $E_n$ having finite measure, then by countable subadditivity,
$$\mu(\{f\neq 0\}) = \mu(X\cap\{f\neq 0\}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n\cap \{f\neq 0\}) = 0$$
